# Right choice to play audio and video content

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, avfoundation, core-audio, audioqueueservices

**What I'm doing :**

I need to play audio and video files that are not supported by Apple on iPhone/iPad for example mkv/mka files which my contain several audio channels.

I'm using libffmpeg to find audio and video streams in media file.
Video is being decoded with `avcodec_decode_video2` and audio with `avcodec_decode_audio3` 
the return values are following for each function are following

- `avcodec_decode_video2` - returns `AVFrame` structure which encapsulates information about the video video frame from the pakcage, specifically is has `data` field which is a pointer to the picture/channel planes.
- `avcodec_decode_audio3` - returns `samples` of type int16_t * which I guess is the raw audio data

So basically I've done all this and successfully decoding the media content.

**What I have to do :**
I've to play the audio and video accordingly using Apples services. The playback I need to perform should support mixing of audio channels while playing video, i.e. let say mkv file contains two audio channel and a video channel. So I would like to know which service will be the appropriate choice for me ? My research showed that AudioQueue service might be useful audio playback, and probably AVFoundation for video.

Please help to find the right technology for my case i.e. video playeback + audio playback with possible audio channel mixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path. If you are only playing audio (not recording at all) then I would use AudioQueues. It will do the mixing for you. If you are recording then you should use AudioUnits. Take a look at the MixerHost example project from Apple. For video I recommend using OpenGL. Assuming the image buffer is in YUV420 then you can render this with a simple two pass shader setup. I do believe there is an Apple example project showing how to do this. In any case you could render any pixel format using OpenGL and a shader to convert the pixel format to RGBA. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the response Steve, basically my app does all, i.e. records, playing mixing audio tracks and playing video. So as I understood from your reply I've to choose 1. Audio Queue : for audio mixing and play 2. AudioUnits : for recording audio 3. OpenGL : for showing video. Did I got it right ?

Comment: I would recommend AudioUnits for everything if you are recording and playing at the same time. In this case you will need to use the Voice Processing IO unit. If you do not then your recordings will contain the output of the speakers. The VP IO unit employs Acoustic Echo Cancelation. Yes OpenGL will more then likely perform the best. I would test other APIs first too see if they are acceptable (e.g. CoreImage or CoreGraphics).